# Apache .htaccess file redirect

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Should be easy for someone.

My files are in this directory: /user/home/peter/mygame/production/

I am required to access my site using: www.foo.com/peter (which brings me to /user/home/peter/)

How do I tell apache:

www.foo.com/peter reads from /user/home/peter/mygame/production/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /peter

# To avoid the infinite loop.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/peter/mygame/production/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mygame/production/$1 [L]
```

(Assuming this is going into "`/user/home/peter/.htaccess`".)